# Error trying to output result of calculation based on user input

Tags: php, html, forms

I recently started PHP and I am not able to figure out how to `echo` the result of this. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <style>
    input[type=submit]{
        background-color: #4CAF50;
        border: none;
        color: white;
        padding: 16px 32px;
        text-decoration: none;
        margin: 4px 2px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    input[type=text]{
        border: 3px solid black;
    }
    </style>
    </head>

    <body>
    <form action="fitness1.php" method="post">
    <b>weight:</b>  <input type="text" name="weight"><br>
    <br>
    <b>height:<b>   <input type="text" name="height"><br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit">
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the PHP code:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php

$WEight = $_Post['weight'];
$HEight = $_post['height'];

if (is_numeric($WEight)&& is_numeric($HEight)){

    $bmi= $WEight / $HEight * $HEight;
  }     

echo ("$bmi");


else {
    echo "please enter your weight and height";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ',' or ';' in G:\wamp\www\test\fitness1.php on line 19

Comment: Move the curly brace before the echo BMI line to be after that line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The case of variables matters in PHP. You're looking for *this*:

```
$WEight = $_POST['weight'];
$HEight = $_POST['height'];
```

Then, this is the logic we would use:

```
if (is_numeric($WEight)&& is_numeric($HEight)) {
    $bmi = $WEight / $HEight * $HEight;
    echo $bmi;
} else {
    echo "please enter your weight and height";
}
```

Your `echo` needs to be inside the `if (...) { ... }` block.

**Edit**:

As requested, here's how I would improve it:

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        input[type=submit]{
            background-color: #4CAF50;
            border: none;
            color: white;
            padding: 16px 32px;
            text-decoration: none;
            margin: 4px 2px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        input[type=text]{
            border: 3px solid black;
        }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form action="fitness1.php" method="post" />
        <b>Weight:</b> <input type="text" name="weight" /><br />
        <br />
        <b>Height:<b>  <input type="text" name="height" /><br />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" />
    </body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
<html>
    <body>
<?php

$weightInKg = (int) $_POST['weight'];
$heightInCm = (int) $_POST['height'];

if ($heightInCm && $weightInKg) {
    $bmi = $weightInKg / pow($heightInCm, 2);
    echo "Your BMI is ${bmi}.";
} else {
    echo "Please enter your height and weight as a number greater than 0.";
}
?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help. Comment if you still can't get it working.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) in G:\wamp\www\test\fitness1.php on line 11

Comment: hey it was still giving error on line 8 and 9 i changed it to $weightInkg and $heightincm it echo bmi but with an error on line 8 of undefined variable

Comment: when i changed variable on line 8 to weightinkg and heightincm it echo's the else statement not the bmi

Comment: Oops my bad as well. Corrected :) You have to use the proper case; PHP variables are case sensitive.

Comment: lol stil an error on line 8 undefined variable height although its echoing the bmi atleast

Comment: sorry for botherin you

Comment: 4th times a charm there we go :) No problem at all, nothing else to do. The condition on line 8 was backwards as well.

Comment: SUCCESS!!! anyway where can i find the best info on php like any forum or website u use? and thanks for helping out bro

Comment: Sweet, no problem! Honestly, just the PHP manual and StackOverflow. I learned PHP and all the other languages I know just by coming up with something to code and trying to figure it out one step at a time. Look at code examples of people doing similar things. You'll get it. Go through code that works line by line and look up how every part of it works.

Comment: Oh and if this is resolved click the checkbox next to the voting arrows to mark it as resolved :)

Answer (score 0):

Main issue of error message is :

```
echo("$bmi"); // this is wrong you don't need brackets.
```

replace this with

```
echo $bmi;
```

That's the reason of error but if would suggest to move echo $bmi inside if condition or initialise $bmi else you can get undefined variable error if it doesn't go through if condition.

Comment: still doesent work now its giving errors on line 5 and 6 and 10 can you write the php code for me it would be more understandable for me

Comment: undefined variable on line 5 6

Comment: fair enough you need to fix typo mistake replace line 4 and 5 ( 
$WEight = $_Post['weight'];
$HEight = $_post['height'];)  by     
$WEight = $_POST['weight'];
$HEight = $_POST['height'];

Comment: yeah but now its not doing the calculation right like 100/2*2 =25 but its echo's 100

Comment: ok did you initialised it with 100? Can you please show your exact code what it looks like now?